# Dynamic list's onClick does not work in React?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new in react.

I want to show a list based on a state. If **showList** is true, show the list and vice versa. But when I click on list element the **selectItem** method does not fired and the list disappears.

But **toggleList** method is working, although both methods are handled same way. I tried making **selectItem** as anonymous method, also bind it in constructr, but no luck.

Can anybody give me a working code for this ?

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Select extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            list:[],
            showList:false,
            selectedItem:''
        }

        // this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this)
    }

    toggleList(e, toggle){
        this.setState({showList:toggle})
    }

    selectItem(e, item){
        alert('')
        this.setState({selectedItem:item.name})
    }


    render(){
        let {showList,selectedItem} = this.state;
        let _this = this;
        let arr = [
            {
                name:'Piyush',
                value: '2'
            }
        ]
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text"
                       onClick={e=>this.toggleList(e, true)}
                       onBlur={e=>this.toggleList(e,false)}
                       value={selectedItem.name}
                />

                {
                    showList &&
                        <div style={{backgroundColor:'#fff', color:'#333', zIndex:9999}}>
                            <ul>
                                {
                                    arr.map(item=>{
                                        return <li key={item.value} id={item.value} onClick={(e)=>this.selectItem(e)}> {item.name} </li>
                                    })
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                }
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `blur` event, the alert will pop up (See [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/88m4jvlko9)). In other words, the `onBlur` takes precedence over `onClick`. It first hides the list, and then tries to handle the click, but by then the list is already removed from the DOM, so you don't see the item getting selected. You need to revise your logic. Maybe use a traditional `<select>`?